# Error when trying to convert a POJO Class to Json String with GSON

Tags: java, json, gson, pojo

I am trying to convert a POJO class to Json using Gson, but when I try to do it I get an error and I have no idea the exact solution.

My Java version is 19 and this is my class:

```
public class PlayerModel {
    String player;
    UUID uuid;
    TribeModel tribe;
    Inventory inventory;

    public PlayerModel(Player p, UUID uuid, Inventory inventory) {
        this.player = p.getDisplayName();
        this.uuid = uuid;
        this.tribe = new TribeModel(this);
        this.inventory = inventory;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return this.player;
    }

    public UUID getUUID() {
        return this.uuid;
    }

    public TribeModel getTribe() {
        return this.tribe;
    }

    public Inventory getInventory() {
        return this.inventory;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PlayerModel [player="
                + player
                + ", uuid=" + uuid
                + ", tribe=" + tribe.toString()
                + ", inventory=" + inventory.toString() + "]";
    }

    public String toJson() {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(this);
        return json;
    }

}
```

and these are the methods I use:

```
 public static void SavePlayerOnFirstJoin(Player player) {
        UUID uuid = player.getUniqueId();
        Document existPlayer = Database.getPlayer(player.getUniqueId());
        if (existPlayer == null) {
            try {
                Document playerDocument = MakePlayerDocument(player, uuid);
                Database.userCollection.insertOne(playerDocument);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                NoWipe.Log.severe(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public static Document MakePlayerDocument(Player player, UUID uuid) {
        String playerModel = new PlayerModel(player, uuid, player.getInventory()).toJson();
        Document parse = Document.parse(playerModel);
        return parse;
    }
```

and this is my complete log of the error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonIOException: Failed making field 'java.lang.ThreadLocal#threadLocalHashCode' accessible; either increase its visibility or write a custom TypeAdapter for its declaring type.
        at com.google.gson.internal.reflect.ReflectionHelper.makeAccessible(ReflectionHelper.java:38) ~[gson-2.10.jar:?]
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287) ~[gson-2.10.jar:?]
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:130) ~[gson-2.10.jar:?]
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:546) ~[gson-2.10.jar:?]
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:160) ~[gson-2.10.jar:?]
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:295) ~[gson-2.10.jar:?]
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:130) ~[gson-2.10.jar:?]
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:546) ~[gson-2.10.jar:?]
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:160) ~[gson-2.10.jar:?]
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:295) ~[gson-2.10.jar:?]
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:130) ~[gson-2.10.jar:?]
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:546) ~[gson-2.10.jar:?]
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:160) ~[gson-2.10.jar:?]
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:295) ~[gson-2.10.jar:?]
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:130) ~[gson-2.10.jar:?]
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:546) ~[gson-2.10.jar:?]
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:817) ~[gson-2.10.jar:?]
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:795) ~[gson-2.10.jar:?]
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:742) ~[gson-2.10.jar:?]
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:719) ~[gson-2.10.jar:?]
        at me.winflix.nowipe.models.PlayerModel.toJson(PlayerModel.java:50) ~[NoWipe.jar:?]
        at me.winflix.nowipe.utils.GlobalUtils.MakePlayerDocument(GlobalUtils.java:30) ~[NoWipe.jar:?]
        at me.winflix.nowipe.utils.GlobalUtils.SavePlayerOnFirstJoin(GlobalUtils.java:24) ~[NoWipe.jar:?]
        at me.winflix.nowipe.events.JoinEvents.PlayerJoinEvent(JoinEvents.java:15) ~[NoWipe.jar:?]
        at com.destroystokyo.paper.event.executor.asm.generated.GeneratedEventExecutor51.execute(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.EventExecutor$2.execute(EventExecutor.java:77) ~[purpur-api-1.19.3-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at co.aikar.timings.TimedEventExecutor.execute(TimedEventExecutor.java:80) ~[purpur-api-1.19.3-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:git-Purpur-1905]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:70) ~[purpur-api-1.19.3-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:680) ~[purpur-api-1.19.3-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.players.PlayerList.placeNewPlayer(PlayerList.java:319) ~[purpur-1.19.3.jar:git-Purpur-1905]
        at net.minecraft.server.network.ServerLoginPacketListenerImpl.placeNewPlayer(ServerLoginPacketListenerImpl.java:202) ~[?:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.network.ServerLoginPacketListenerImpl.handleAcceptedLogin(ServerLoginPacketListenerImpl.java:183) ~[?:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.network.ServerLoginPacketListenerImpl.tick(ServerLoginPacketListenerImpl.java:85) ~[?:?]
        at net.minecraft.network.Connection.tick(Connection.java:594) ~[?:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.network.ServerConnectionListener.tick(ServerConnectionListener.java:233) ~[?:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.tickChildren(MinecraftServer.java:1594) ~[purpur-1.19.3.jar:git-Purpur-1905]
        at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.tickChildren(DedicatedServer.java:482) ~[purpur-1.19.3.jar:git-Purpur-1905]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.tickServer(MinecraftServer.java:1424) ~[purpur-1.19.3.jar:git-Purpur-1905]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.runServer(MinecraftServer.java:1194) ~[purpur-1.19.3.jar:git-Purpur-1905]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$spin$0(MinecraftServer.java:321) ~[purpur-1.19.3.jar:git-Purpur-1905]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final int java.lang.ThreadLocal.threadLocalHashCode accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @2e24b18c
        at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.throwInaccessibleObjectException(AccessibleObject.java:387) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:363) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:311) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:180) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:174) ~[?:?]
        at com.google.gson.internal.reflect.ReflectionHelper.makeAccessible(ReflectionHelper.java:35) ~[gson-2.10.jar:?]
        ... 40 more
```

I have read about creating a TypeAdapter from the POJO to Gson but I still don't fully understand how to do it and thanks to everyone :)

I also tried with Jackson but it gives me another huge error that if necessary I insert it in this post :)

Comment: Serialising a ThreadLocal is probably not what you want to do -- you should consider excluding that field from serialization.

Comment: @tgdavies And how do I do that? what I'm looking for is to convert it to Json String to save it in a mongodb collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75349143/error-when-trying-to-convert-a-pojo-class-to-json-string-with-gson#comment132955395_75349143) your code indirectly tries to serialize a `java.lang.ThreadLocal`. Gson has no built-in adapter for that class so it tries to use reflection, which fails because internal fields of JDK classes cannot be accessed using reflection, see also the [Gson troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/Troubleshooting.md#inaccessibleobjectexception-module--does-not-opens--to-unnamed-module).

The field of type `ThreadLocal` is not directly in your `PlayerModel` class but nested, either in `TribeModel` or `Inventory` (or nested in some of the classes of their fields). Depending on your use case, you could either:

- check if the `ThreadLocal` field (or even its declaring class) really has to be serialized and deserialized, and if not [exclude it](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#excluding-fields-from-serialization-and-deserialization), or
- write a custom [`TypeAdapter`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) which serializes and deserializes `ThreadLocal` instances. For example by calling their `get()` method to obtain the value during serialization, respectively creating a new instance and calling `set(...)` to set the value during deserialization.